# When using UIDocumentPicker, is there a way to know which external app the document is coming from?

Tags: ios, uidocumentpickervc

I am using the UIDocumentPicker from iOS 8, uploading various documents from a number of different external apps such as Dropbox and Google Drive. Is there some way where I can know which app the user is getting the document from?

Comment: Curious - why do you need to know? It shouldn't matter where it comes from.

Comment: Before I started using the document picker I had my own custom upload method. After using one of those to upload a document the user would be able to see, "Uploaded from Google Drive/Dropbox/etc on May 16, 2016". Thanks for the answer, by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no API that provides this information. All you know is a temporary file URL for the selected file (when using the Import mode).